# Magento 2 : How to replace dropdown as switch?

Tags: magento2.2, drop-downs, switcher

I've created a custom module in  which I've a drop down field having "Yes/No" value, here is the screenshot:

> https://nimb.ws/bMZCUB

**I just want to replace this drop down into switch** ,just like below screenshot:

> https://nimb.ws/OCldgW

How can I achieve the same?

I've created module from "Silksoftware" and to creating the form fields it's using block just like:

```
   $fieldset->addField(
            'available_every_week',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Available Every Week'),
                'title' => __('Available Every Week'),
                'name' => 'available_every_week',

                'options' => \Namespace\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Gametype\Grid::getOptionArray5(),
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );
```

Where

> Namespace\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Gametype\Grid::getOptionArray5

is returning values(Yes/No) for the dropdown.

Waiting for the update.

Comment: thanks for the reply,this doesn't work getting " Class boolean does not exist" problem.
https://nimb.ws/DEUX8o

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your form using UI component library provided in magento 2.

Use below example:

```
<field name="available_every_week" formElement="checkbox">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
        </validation>
        <dataType>boolean</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Available Every Week</label>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <checkbox>
            <settings>
                <valueMap>
                    <map name="false" xsi:type="string">0</map>
                    <map name="true" xsi:type="string">1</map>
                </valueMap>
                <prefer>toggle</prefer>
            </settings>
        </checkbox>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I've created from Silksoftware,which is creating form just like Magento 1 way.is this possible to add switch in this?

Comment: No, it is not possible without UI component form.